# Basic Dataset calling

Tags: r, dataset

I have just begun using R and I have a rather basic question regarding how to properly create syntax to interact with values in a dataset.

I am working with the mtcars dataset that is set in r.

I have created a variable called `mydata` which contains the dataset and am trying to answer the following questions:

> a) Which car has highest mpg?
>   b) What horsepower does "Honda Civic" have?
>   c) What are the values for "Porsche 914-2"

Here is what I have attempted thus far:
a)

```
y <- max(mydata$mpg) #I know this gives me max value of all mpg values<br/>
rownames(mydata$y) #know rownames gives me the name of all vehicles<br/> 
NULL #Error message produced <br/>
```

b)

```
mydata$hp #know this gives all the numerical values of cars horsepowers<br/>
```

c)

```
rownames(x == "Porsche 914-2") <br/>
NULL #error produced <br/>
```

a) Should return Toyota Corolla as it is the highest mpg vehicle in dataset
b) Should return `52`
c) Should return `26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2`

When I run I just getting variety of errors or unexpected symbols messages

Comment: It would help us to help you if you shared the error messages.

Comment: I'd spend some time getting to know the basic `index`ing functions for data.frames. [Here is one good source](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/modules/subsetting-data/) for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here is one option:

```
a) row.names(mtcars[mtcars[,"mpg"] == max(mtcars[,"mpg"]),])

b) mtcars["Honda Civic","hp"] 

c) mtcars["Porsche 914-2",]
```